# Glassfish websocket OnMessage method exit suddenly

Tags: java, multithreading, methods, websocket, glassfish

I have a simple code to attend webSocket received messages:

```
    @OnMessage
public void handleMessage(String message, Session session) {
    System.out.println("1");
    EntradaInicial entrada = new EntradaInicial();
    entrada.setTipoEntrada(TipoEntrada.MENU_API);
    System.out.println("2");
    System.out.println("3");
    MenuApiInput he = new MenuApiInput();
    he.setTipoRequisicao(TipoRequisicaoMenuApi.CRIAR_SALA);
    System.out.println("4");
    ...
```

Inexplicably, the console output is just:

```
    1
    2
    3
```

It looks like the thread gets lost in the MenuApiInput() constructor, but it's a default constructor:

```
public MenuApiInput() {}
```

It don't give any exception, just continue the execution like if the method returned normally.

Somebody can help?

Answer (score 0):

Could be two things:

1. Something killed the websocket thread;
2. The websocket component of Glassfish eats the log.

I bet on 2. Would not be the first time [GlassFish does not log exceptions thrown by WebSocket callback methods](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20481).